# Instantiated Object sometimes gives NullReference but sometimes not

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

So i am trying to make a simple gameobject saving system in Unity.

Whenever i place an cube i enter it in a GameObject called currentCube

```
GameObject currentCube = new GameObject();
currentCube = Instantiate(CubeBlue, placeLocation, new Quaternion());
```

This places my cube all good and well. Then just for debugging i check if the currentCube actually has the just placed Cube

```
print(currentCube.transform.position);
```

This does indeed give the location of my newly placed Cube. But then i try to add the cube to a List (also tried with an array)

```
cubes.Add(currentCube);
```

But then i get a NullReferenceException

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

And then with the Script filename and the location line of where i put the "cubes.Add(currentCube;)"

EDIT:

Also in my part above the void start i have stated
`private List<GameObject> cubes;`

Comment: Why do you think `currentCube` is the problem for the NullReferenceException you got at `cubes.Add(currentCube)`? Did you verify in the debugger that `currentCube` is actually null when executing this code line? And why would you think that it would not be possible to add a `null` value to the list (and this causing a NullReferenceException, as you seem to believe)?

Comment: Where do you initialize `cubes`? Based on the code you've provided, that seems more likely to cause the NRE.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace well that is just what looks like the problem to me, what i forgot to add is that i have this in my class as well 

private List<GameObject> cubes;

Im not that known to using Lists but this looked like the problem to me atleast

Comment: @gunr2171 I indeed forgot to mention that, i edited it now. But i have it at the top of my code as 

private List<GameObject> cubes;

Comment: That's where you _declare_ the variable, where do you _initialize_ `cubes`?

Comment: @gunr2171 ah, it seems i indeed missed the part of initializing the list. thats where the problem was.
i just added "cubes = new List<GameObject>();" and now i no longer get the error and when checking the amount of objects in the list it indeed works now

Comment: Here's more info about that problem. [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @gunr2171 Oh that looks like quite a handy read to look through. For now you fixed my problem but i will definitely give that page a read since it looks quite handy for in the future

Comment: You know that `GameObject currentCube = new GameObject();
currentCube = Instantiate(CubeBlue, placeLocation, new Quaternion());` will actually create **two** new objects in your scene right?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your List is not getting Initialized. Try

```
private List<GameObject> cubes = new List<GameObject>();
```

Comment: he did not initialized, do give him the knowledge too of why initialization is important :), giving you one upvote for picking up one of the possibility of solution (could be only but still)